# Composer giving error while installing package with $composer update command

Tags: laravel, composer-php, package

I am trying to install tomcorbett/opentok-laravel package. I am encountering the that error.

```
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.6.12
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.12
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.11
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.10
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.9
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.8
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.7
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.6
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.5
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.4
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.2
- Installation request for tomcorbett/opentok-laravel dev-master -> satisfiable by tomcorbett/opentok-laravel[dev-master].
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.1
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
... and goes on
```

and my composer.json is

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "hamog/captcha": "^1.2",
    "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
    "laravel/socialite": "^3.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
    "nexmo/laravel": "^1.1",
    "santigarcor/laratrust": "5.0.*",
    "tomcorbett/opentok-laravel": "dev-master"
},
"require-dev": {
    "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
},
and goes on..
```

I can not handle this problem. I searched very much, but there are nothing about it. Is it a composer problem or package problem. Please help me. I am new on PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the `composer.json` file for `tomcorbett/opentok-laravel` (https://github.com/tomcorbett/opentok-laravel/blob/master/composer.json), that package only supports Laravel 5.0-5.4, while you require Laravel 5.6 in your `composer.json`.

Comment: I guess I dont have a chance to use this package with laravel 5.6 :(

Comment: You can always open an issue with the package on GitHub and ask the author to update the package for Laravel 5.6.

Comment: Thanks, I try it. I wish to do it myself :)